# Laravel: Populate Form dropdown from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

First Laravel Project.

I want to make a form drop-down list what is populated from mysql database. I found this on the documentation:

```
Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'))
```

and I tried this:

```
{{Form::select('size', array(
                @foreach ($suppliers as $supplier)
                $supplier->id => $supplier->name
                @endforeach
))
}}
```

But I got syntax error:

> ErrorException in e34a9587ee23853b6d4c489cc0ed13515fad9c06.php line
>   23: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')' (View:
>   /var/www/html/project/laravel/leltar/resources/views/invoice.blade.php)

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pluck returns a collection from laravel version 5.3 and that answer is wrong, it wont show the select box right!

Here is the right solution!

```
$suppliers = Supplier::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

and in view call it like this:

```
{!! Form::select('supplier', $suppliers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

---

#### update for Laravel 5.5

Just tested this and in Laravel 5.5 pluck() works without appending toArray() on it like this:

```
$tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');
```

or for this question;

```
$tags = Supplier::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck):

```
Form::select('size', $suppliers->pluck('name', 'id')->all())
```

Comment: I got an another error message: "Call to a member function pluck() on array (View: /var/www/html/project/laravel/leltar/resources/views/invoice.blade.php)"

Comment: how do you send `$suppliers` from controller?

Comment: `$suppliers = DB::select('select * from supplier');
return view('invoice',['suppliers'=>$suppliers]);`

Comment: `$suppliers = SupplierModel::all();` try it using the model instead of a raw query